# Clear ComboBox only works sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox`, which holds a 3rd level selection (*Parent-category* > *Sub-category* > *Brand*). When any of the two higher level categories are changed, the `DataSource` for the Brand selection should be refreshed, and the selection reset.

Now this works quite well for the Sub-category selection, but not for the Parent-category selection Despite using almost identical syntax.

I could of course just make a quick fix, using `cboBrand.Text = string.Empty`, but the thing is, that the brand combo box still holds the same number of slots as before, just empty. I.e. if there was 3 brand options before changing the parent category, there will be 3 empty slots in the drop down list. I have checked, and the `Count()` of `viewModel.BrandOptions` is zero, so this is not the issue.

Does anyone have any idea, what I am doing wrong?

**Parent-category Changed (does not work)**

```
private void cboCategory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.Category = (CategoryModel)cboCategory.SelectedItem;

    // Update sub-category data source
    cboSubCategory.DataSource = viewModel.SubCategoryOptions;

    // Update Brand data source and reset selection
    cboBrand.DataSource = viewModel.BrandOptions;
    cboBrand.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

**Sub-category Changed (this one works fine)**

```
private void cboSubCategory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboCategory.SelectedItem != null)
        viewModel.SubCategory = (CategoryModel)cboSubCategory.SelectedItem;

    // Update Brand data source and reset selection
    cboBrand.DataSource = viewModel.BrandOptions;
    cboBrand.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

**Update**

Setting `cboBrand.DataSource = null` will make it clear the combo box. But it does not fix the multiple blank rows, in the drop down list. I have also checked (before changing the data source to null) if there was any objects in the data source. This was not the case, as you can see in the image.

[image]

Comment: In the case when it doesn't work, when you look at `viewModel.BrandOptions` in the debugger, what do you see in that collection?

Comment: There is nothing in the BrandOptions collection. And also nothing in the drop down list, expect **X** blank rows.

Comment: If you assign an empty collection to cboBrand.DataSource, you should expect cboBrand to have nothing in it. It appears that your problem is that `viewModel.BrandOptions` should be populated somehow, somewhere, in code you didn't show us -- but that's not happening. Or possibly, it is happening and you're immediately clearing it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett when I change the parent-category, the sub-category will be set to a default object, with no related brands. Hence I expect the BrandOptions to be empty, and it is. What I do not get is: 1) Why are there still **X** empty rows in the drop down and 2) Why wont it clear the selection.

Comment: That's not code. It's a description of what you assume your code is doing, at such a high level of abstraction that even if correct it tells me nothing. I can't debug it or use it to reproduce the issue. Because you're seeing unexpected behavior that you don't understand, it is very unlikely that your code is doing what you think it is. Good luck with your problem. It's much easier to help [when there's an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting:

```
private void cboCategory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.Category = (CategoryModel)cboCategory.SelectedItem;

    // Update sub-category data source
    cboSubCategory.DataSource = viewModel.SubCategoryOptions;
    cboSubCategory.SelectedIndex = -1; // << new line to blank out SubCat

    // Update Brand data source and reset selection
    cboBrand.DataSource = viewModel.BrandOptions;
    cboBrand.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

... I have a feeling that what's going on is that you're refreshing two data sources in two sequential lines, and that it's a timing issue - cboBrand is trying to refresh its data before cboSubCategory has the correct value in place.

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. Also I think what I am seeing, is two different issues, with two different causes (see update in original post).